# sudo pecl install mongodb problem | unknown type name 'pcre_cache_entry'

Tags: php, mongodb, pcre, pecl

I'm trying to install mongodb exentsion for php 8.0.13 on my MacOS Monterey.

I try `sudo pecl install mongodb` command: and then get below errror.

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@8.0/8.0.13/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:151:4: error: unknown type name 'pcre_cache_entry'
                    pcre_cache_entry *pce;
                    ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [php_phongo.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

[image]

which php: `/opt/homebrew/bin/php`
php -v: `PHP 8.0.13 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2021 13:11:14) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.0.13, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v8.0.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies`

Can anyone help me for fix this error?
Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compile MongoDB using PECL you will have to copy the `pcre2.h` to php's include directory.

For php@8.0, you can do this, But you will have to do this after every PHP release or if you switch the PHP version.

```
pcre2_h="$(find "$(brew --cellar pcre2)" -name "pcre2.h")"
cp -f "$pcre2_h" "$(brew --cellar php@8.0)"/*/include/php/ext/pcre
```

To avoid this I would recommend using [shivammathur/extensions](https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-extensions) brew tap for installing PHP extensions.

Comment: Hi @Shivam Mathur . Thanks for sharing your knowledge. But the pcre2.h is already exists in include/php/ext/pcre directory. before this error I got /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.9/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:23:10: fatal error: 'pcre2.h' file not found
#include "pcre2.h"

And after copy the pcre2.h file to ext/pcre directory the error changed to 
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@8.0/8.0.13/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:151:4: error: unknown type name 'pcre_cache_entry'
                    pcre_cache_entry *pce;
                    ^

These 2 errors are a little diffrent

Comment: Thank you so much @Shivam Mathur.
Finally I easily installed mongodb extension for my MAMP php (version 8.0.8) with using  shivammathur/extensions brew tap.
Well done.